# Sencha Touch 2 and .focus() : set cursor into textarea

Tags: javascript, cursor, focus, sencha-touch-2, textarea

I want to set a cursor into the textarea with `id="mytextarea"` when a new View with a textarea appears.

Seems like .focus() should work, but it doesn't. Why?

```
console.log('this message is displayed');//displayed in console
Ext.getCmp('mytextarea').focus();//nothing happens at the same time
```

And this is what I have in Chrome:

```
<div class="x-container x-field-textarea x-field x-label-align-left x-form-label-nowrap x-empty" id="mytextarea">
    <div class="x-form-label" id="ext-element-127" style="width: 30% !important;">
        <span id="ext-element-128"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="x-component-outer" id="ext-element-126">
        <div class="x-unsized x-field-input sencha-clear-icon" id="ext-textareainput-1">
            <textarea id="ext-element-129" class="x-input-el x-form-field x-input-text" type="text" autocapitalize="off" placeholder="Type here...">
            </textarea>
            <div class="x-field-mask" id="ext-element-130" style="display: none !important;">
            </div>
            <div class="x-clear-icon" id="ext-element-131">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post sample code to jsfiddle.net?

Comment: same problem here. Did you solved it?

Comment: @sur007: No, I don't.

Comment: Did you got any workout to overcome this?

Comment: No, I've just left it as it is. Don't work on this problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I need move cursor to the End of Texarea. Use SenchaTouch 2.3.0 / iOS. I did it set focus to the textfield and set new value  soo. when I open popup - textfeld will be focused and caret positon at the end of the text.

```
var textarea = document.getElementById('note'),
    note = textarea.getValue();

textarea.focus(); 
textarea.setValue('');//without this nothing happend 
textarea.setValue(note);
```